# Conflict with languages at home page

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have enabled 2 languages on the site (Russian and English). The conflict is only happening at the home page where the URL alias is */*. All the strings at sitename.ru/ are in English (the ones I would expect on sitename.co.uk), except for blocks. Language seems set to Russian, if that is the language set for the blocks.
All the other pages (sitename.ru/pagename) are working correctly.

[Here are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6tD8.jpg) some screenshots of page configuration, modules list and language configuration from admin.

How do I make it work on / for all languages based on their TLD?

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is happening because you set the default language as English (see: /admin/config/regional/language) and set Russian as default to have Russian language on "/" .

Comment: So? How do you fix it by having both languages using TLD at /